# custom asm mnemonics unrecognized in current riscv-gnu-toolchain

Tags: riscv

For example, the following assembler statement should translate to the opcode `0x0000000b`

```
custom0 0,0,0,0
```

With an older version of riscv-gnu-toolchain (built on Jun 4th) no -march= option was needed to assemble this. However, with todays git head of [riscv-tools](https://github.com/riscv/riscv-tools) I get:

```
$ /opt/riscv_new/bin/riscv64-unknown-elf-as -m32 test.s
test.s: Assembler messages:
test.s:1: Error: unrecognized opcode `custom0 0,0,0,0'
```

From reading the source code I'd guess passing the arch `Xcustom` to the tools should fix that, but:

```
$ /opt/riscv_new/bin/riscv64-unknown-elf-as -m32 -march=RV32IMXcustom test.s 
test.s: Assembler messages:
test.s:1: Error: unrecognized opcode `custom0 0,0,0,0'
```

(At the moment the PicoRV32 test firmware does not build with the latest riscv-gnu-toolchain [because of this](https://github.com/cliffordwolf/picorv32/blob/master/firmware/custom_ops.S).)

Edit: The last version of riscv-tools that work for me is commit 84a47e0b4e from Aug 20. With that version the custom0 opcode is recognized with and without the `-march=` option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry this took so long to find -- I don't read stackoverflow.  For future reference, if you submit a github issue/PR or email me directly, I'll deal with these sorts of things.

A fix should be here, do you mind verifying it?
https://github.com/riscv/riscv-gnu-toolchain/pull/97

Sorry for introducing the regression!

Answer (score 1):

I also faced this issue, in yesterdays update of the gnu toolchain if you look into the opcodes.custom file in the risv-opcodes folder, all the custom opcodes are commented, you need to uncomment those that you need and recompile the toolchain

Comment: I am having problems with RoCC. Ideally custom 0 instruction should activate the RoCC template of the rocket chip but I'm just unable to figure out the right parameter to give to the variable "BuildRocc" in configs.scala in order to enable the RoCC interface and get the dummy accumulator example working

Comment: hmm.. do you mean `opcodes-custom` in `riscv-opcodes/`? On my machine the lines there only have the `@`-sign at the beginning indicating they are pseudo-ops (comment would be with a `#`). Removing the `@`-sign and rebuilding has no effect.

Comment: After you remove the @, you need to do make install in the riscv-opcodes folder and then ruin the build script in the riscv-tools, then the custom commands start working

Comment: Then I get a bunch of errors like this one when building `riscv-gnu-toolchain`: `/home/clifford/Temp/riscv-tools/riscv-gnu-toolchain/build/src/binutils/bfd/../include/opcode/riscv.h:159:5: error: ‘MATCH_AUIPC’ undeclared (first use in this function)
   ((MATCH_ ## insn) | ((rd) << OP_SH_RD) | ENCODE_UTYPE_IMM(bigimm))
/home/clifford/Temp/riscv-tools/riscv-gnu-toolchain/build/src/binutils/bfd/elfnn-riscv.c:202:14: note: in expansion of macro ‘RISCV_UTYPE’
   entry[0] = RISCV_UTYPE (AUIPC, X_T2, gotplt_offset_high);`

Comment: Ok this seems to be some other issue, yesterday there were a lot of successive pushes pushes to the main rocket chip repository in git, only after 3 successful git resets and git submodule pulls i could eliminate all the errors in both rocket as well as toolchain builds